# Only call function after after a specific value on screen resize

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function on screen resize but only if the screen goes over or under a specific value rather than every time the screen is resized.

In this example, I only want to call a function when the isMobile value has changed.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth < mobileSize) {
    isMobile = true;
  } else {
    isMobile = false;
  }
  // call function only isMobile changes from true to false or vice-versa
});
```

Comment: It seems that the `isMobile` will change everytime when the screen is resized by even a minor value due to that `if-else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store a reference to the last `isMobile` value, and check if the value changed inside the function:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const lastIsMobile = isMobile;
  isMobile = window.innerWidth < mobileSize;
  if (lastIsMobile !== isMobile) woohoo()
});
```

Note that if `isMobile` is really an Object or an Array, those are pass by reference in JavaScript, which means that mutating the value of `isMobile` will mutate the value of `lastIsMobile`. Booleans are pass by value in JavaScript, though, so `lastIsMobile` won't be mutated in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const isMobilePrevious = isMobile;
  isMobile = window.innerWidth < mobileSize;

  if (isMobilePrevious === isMobile) return;

  // call your function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last value and check for a change:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  const wasMobile = isMobile;
  if (window.innerWidth < mobileSize) {
    isMobile = true;
  } else {
    isMobile = false;
  }
  // call function only isMobile changes from true to false or vice-versa
  if (wasMobile != isMobile) {
    someFunction();
  }
});
```

But for responsive design I strongly recommend taking a look at [CSS media rules](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS%20media%20rules).